# OpenERP. Add image into field dynamically in a tree view

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I am using **v7** and I want to show in a `tree view` a field with image icons (like a semaphore) depending of other field values in the same row.

Actually, I get the functionality I want with a function field and put the result as string but I really want it as an image. I don't know if is possible to return `HTML` from the function so I decided to do that with `jQuery`.

I implemented the `jQuery` code using the browser console and works but when I put the `jQuery code` in the view the "data-field" selector does not selected.

Please, can anyone explain me why or tell me another way to get my objective?

Comment: Did you know that there is an attribute `colors` to change the font color of the row? Example: `<tree colors="blue:state == 'draft';black:state in ('proforma','proforma2','open');gray:state == 'cancel'" string="Invoice">`

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to get it with images, not just colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lists**

The root element of list views is **tree**. The list view's root can have the following attributes:

editable, default_order, colors, fonts, create, edit, delete, on_write, string

See more about [ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825447/openerp-add-image-into-field-dynamically-in-a-tree-view)

You can achieve this by defining child elements **button** in list view.
I have added icon in product to show whether product is available / hold / sold based on product's status.

- **button**

  **icon**: icon to use to display the button

Xml code to display icon in listview.

```
<xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Order Lines']/field[@name='order_line']/tree[@string='Sales Order Lines']/field[@name='product_id']" position="before">
      <field name="product_status" invisible="1" />
      <button icon='Hold' readonly="1" attrs="{'invisible':[('product_status', '!=', 'hold')]}"/>
      <button icon='Available' readonly="1" attrs="{'invisible':[('product_status', '!=', 'available')]}"/>
      <button icon='sold' readonly="1" attrs="{'invisible':[('product_status', '!=', 'sold')]}"/>
</xpath>
```

**NOTE**

- Remember base field on which you defined button's visibility must be
  present on listview, doesn't matter whether it's visible or not but it
  must be there, like **product_status** in above example.
- base field must be **store=True**.

  Why **store=True** ?

> **Reason:** when you set any function field **store=True** then it will physically created in database, while you give this field name in
>   domain the odoo framework add this field directly in **WHERE** clause,
>   it will not access through browsable object, so if your field is
>   **store=False** then it won't be able to find that field and gives you an error.

- icons must be present in **web/static/src/img/icons**.
- if you want to keep icons in your custom module then you have to create the same hierarchy for that in side your module folder create **/static/src/img/icons** and keep all the icons there.

xpath is used to define at which location you want to add/update fields.

See more about [xpath](http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/xpath-expressions-in-odoo-8/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is a simply way to get that I need.

Comment: Just a detail. In my case the dependent field is a function field. So in this case the store attribute must be False.

Comment: @NachoSalvador: See I have updated answer with reason why you need to set store=True.

Comment: You can set your field store=True and set watch to update it's value when dependent fields are updated.

Comment: I put my custom icons in myModule/static/src/img/icons but odoo searchs the icons only in addons/web/static/src/img/icons. What I have to do add this other path to the search icons path?